# VBA to run event after selecting option out of select list on a web page

Tags: html, vba

I 'm currently working on an access database project and i 've decided it's time to make a bigger step by trying the website automation. So, considering the fact that I 'm new to the "Internet Explorer Object" area, I would appreciate it if you could help me with something. I have discovered how to track the html elements i want to work with and how to get their value or the opposite. The point is that on the website I 'm working on, there is a hidden button which in order to make it appear you 'll have to click on the first option out of dropdown list. I 've tried everything i found online but still I can't make the button appear, and so i cannot "click" it via VBA. Here 's the VBA code I use:

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
Dim oHTML As HTMLOptionElement

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
 
objIE.Visible = True
 
objIE.Navigate "https://registration.dikaiomata.gr/user_registration/"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
   
For Each oHTML In objIE.Document.getElementById("appSelect").getElementsByTagName("option")
   If oHTML.value = "gaee2020" Then
         oHTML.Click
   End If
Next
```

Here is the dropdownlist HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<script type="text/javascript">
var BASE_APP_URL = 'https://registration.dikaiomata.gr/user_registration/apps/index.php?m=';
</script>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="appSelect">
    <option value="0">-- Επιλέξτε --</option>
    <option value="gaee2020">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2020 (ΕΑΕ2020)</option>
    <option value="gaee2019">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2019 (ΕΑΕ2019)</option>
    <option value="gaee2018">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2018 (ΕΑΕ2018)</option>
    <option value="gaee2017">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2017 (ΕΑΕ2017)</option>
    <option value="M101AEO">Μέτρο 10.1 "Αμπελώνες Ελαιώνες Ορνιθοπανίδα"</option>
    <option value="M1018">Μέτρο 10 (Δράσεις 10.1.08 – 10.1.07)</option>
    <option value="M1014">Δράση 10.1.04 "Μείωση της ρύπανσης νερού από γεωργική δραστηριότητα"</option>
    <option value="M1019">Δράση 10.1.09 "Διατήρηση Απειλούμενων Αυτόχθονων Φυλών Αγροτικών Ζώων"</option>
    <option value="bpe">Μεταβιβάσεις Δικαιωμάτων Βασικής Ενίσχυσης (ΜΔΒΕ) 2015-2020</option>
    <option value="FarmersTab">Καρτέλα Αγρότη</option>
    <option value="Organics16">Μέτρο 11 του ΠΑΑ 2014-2020 (Βιολογικά)</option>
    <option value="gaee2016">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2016 (ΕΑΕ2016)</option>
    <option value="gaee2015">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2015 (ΕΑΕ2015)</option>
    <option value="gaee2014">Ενιαία Αίτηση Ενίσχυσης 2014 (ΕΑΕ2014)</option>
    <option value="RDIIS">Ο.Π.Σ.Α.Α. 2014-2020</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And here is the HTML code for the button i want to reach:

```
<a href="#modal4pyli" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal4pyli">
        Κωδικός υποβολής <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

All I want is to click that button so I can go further away with my code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, all i needed to do was to trigger the appropriate event to make the button appear, using the code below:

```
Set event_onChange = HTMLdoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
objIE.document.querySelector("#appSelect").value = "gaee2020"
objIE.document.querySelector("#appSelect").dispatchEvent event_onChange
```